# What is the meaning of Poker Chips?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Prison, Hydell(prisoner) ready to hurt Emilie Warnock(interrogator) 
but Alex(prisoner) came and stopped him. Before this incident, Hydell 
released all the prisoners(including Alex). So Alex said this words to Hydell
while stopping Hydell:

> In less than an hour, all these people, including young Emilie Warnock
>   here, will be the only thing keeping us alive. You don't mess with
>   your **poker chips**.

Comment: You should indicate the source of this quote, with a link if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poker Chips are game tokens that are used to wager.  The player's pile of Poker Chips represents their winnings, and by extension their power.  Someone who loses all of their Poker Chips is out of the game, while someone who has won extra Poker Chips from other players can afford to be reckless.

In the quote you provided, the character is describing Emilie as something that will be "keeping them alive".  This sounds like a "hostage negotiation", where one side has captured some of the enemy, and believes the other side will make a favorable deal to ensure their safe return.  Furthermore, having hostages might prevent the other side from using violence, because they do not want to risk hurting the hostages during an attack.

In this case, some or all of the power that the Prisoners have is tied up in their hostages.  They are like a gambler with only a few Poker Chips left to play, so they cannot afford to be reckless.  When Alex is explaining the value of keeping the Hostages healthy, he uses the metaphor of risking (or "messing with") your Poker Chips, because Hydell understands the wisdom of protecting your power in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Poker Chips are the tokens used in the card game of poker to denote the bets that various players have made around the table.

In games that are played for stakes these chips will have set values a red one may be £5, blues ones £10, green £20 etc. depending on the local currency and the values set at the table.

Presuming the scenario is a hostage situation then Emille Warnock represents something of value that the Authorities will want to be returned unharmed, if Hydell messes with her he will metaphorically reduce her value.

Answer (score -1):

My guess = don't spoil your trump card.

[mess with something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mess+with)
2. to change something in a way that is likely to cause harm *Crime really messes with the quality of life in a community. Don't mess with funding for education programs that have a direct impact on student learning.*

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.